# Generating data from Probit regression, cut off 0 and variance 1 necessary?

Tags: r, multiple-regression, variance, probit, latent-variable

I am trying to create a dataset using a Probit regression model in R, where I have an intercept and three covariates. I first fix a set of coefficients for the three covariates, generate these covariates using standard normal or binomial functions. Then I generate the latent variable Z from a normal distribution centered on my linear function of coefficients and covariates and with variance 1. Then I generate the response variable which takes values 0 or 1, depending on a whether my latent variable Z is below or above 0.

**My question:** is it necessary to have a variance 1 for Z, the latent variable? If I set this to be some other value, does it mean I will first have to scale Z? See code below for this example. Also, does the cut off value need to be 0? I see that this seems to be a standard assumption but how  can I have this different, if possible?

My code is:

```
nobs <- 5000               # observations
t.beta <- c(1, 1.2, -4, 2) # Coefficients 
X <- cbind(rep(1, nobs), rnorm(nobs, -4, sqrt(2.5)), rbinom(nobs, 1, 0.4), rnorm(nobs, 3, sqrt(2))) 
Z <- rnorm(nrow(X), (X%*%t.beta), 1)   
Y <- as.matrix(ifelse(Z<0, 0, 1))
```

When I run a standard probit regression on this dataset:

```
probitModel<- glm(Y~X[,2]+as.factor(X[,3])+X[,4],     family=binomial(link="probit")) 
summary(probitModel)
```

In this code, if I change the variance of Z, or use a different cut-off, when I run the `probitModel` I do not get the correct coefficients. Why is this so? Is it not possible to use a different cut-off or variance for Z?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A latent variable has no scale of itself, i.e. it is not measured in meters, inches, yen, kilos, so we need to give it one otherwise we don't know what we are measuring. In probit we fix the latent variable's scale by setting the residual variance to 1. You can change that if you want, but than you will get differen parameter estimates, because your dependent variable will have a different scale.

So, if you want to create data for a probit and the coefficients you put into it should be the same as the coefficients you get out when estimating a probit regression, then you need to fix the residual variance to 1.

Comment: Ah, I see the intuition now. Thank you very much. Would you also perhaps be aware of a guide/book/lecture on reasons why this variance or the cut-off could be chosen differently and how to perform that analysis?

Comment: Start with estimating a regular probit. If you want the residual standard deviation to be a number $\varepsilon$, you just divide all the coefficients by $\varepsilon$. Now you have your estimates with a probit with a residual standard deviation of $\varepsilon$. There is no way to choose between the models, they lead to exactly the same predictions. This is what one means when one says that the residial standard deviation is not identified in a probit (logit) model: there is no information whatsoever in the data that can help you estimate it.

Comment: Normally we arbitrarily fix the residual standard deviation of a probit at 1, but if you want it to be $\sqrt{\frac{\pi^2}{3}}$ or any other number you think pretty or otherwise desirable then that is fine too. However, if you choose an other number you need to be very clear in communicating it...

Comment: Thanks, that helps to understand better that the variance of Z is not identifiable. How about the value where  we truncate the latent variable, Z, in the analysis? Again, this seems to be set in the built-in function at 0. Just like I generate Y above when Z<=0. What if I put 0.5, why can't I recover the coefficients? Or how can I take this into account when I analyse?

Comment: The cut-point just influences the constant. If you want your cutvalue to be some number $c$ instead of the default 0, you just subtract $c$ from the constant. Again, you can choose any number you like, but if you choose a number other than 0 you need to be very careful to communicate that clearly.

Comment: I see. I think it might be helpful for me to see some applications in finance or medicine to see how users choose _c_ in practice. You've been very helpful in clarifying things, thanks.

Comment: In real research you **never** change either $c$ or $\varepsilon$. It is always 0 and 1. Changing these has no added value, as the predicted values are _exactly_ the same. Changing these has a big cost in the sense that it will lead to a lot of confusion in the audience. No benefit but a real cost adds up to "don't do that".

Comment: I see, yes, it makes sense to me now. One more question, what happens if the linear function XB, on which Z is centered has a range of values not centered at 0, say a range from 2 to 30. I am sure that is common. In my simulation I kept them centered at 0 roughly. Do analysts first scale variables somehow before running the analyses then, since they are trying to keep _c=0_?

Comment: That will happen when the observed variable has many 1s. Remember that there is also an error term that can push the latent variable below 0. Since the linear predictor is larger than 0 in your example this will happen rarely. From the (assumed) distribution of the error term we know how rarely: $\Phi(X\beta)$. Informally, you can think of probit as comparing the  probabilities implied by the model with proportions observed in the data. We than choose $\beta$ such that the fit is best. So we don't need to do any additional scaling on top of deciding values for $c$ and $\varepsilon$.